# Is it possible using sphinx to link to a specific URL using the :class: role?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to document a python package that wraps a proprietary API that wasn't documented using Sphinx as far as I can tell. The API documentation provides useful information, but the URL's are not in a format that sphinx can automatically generate links for. Is it possible to mark a string semantically as a class, while specifying the link target by hand?

I tried:

```
:class:`Class <https://api.documentation/some/path/to_class_constructor.htm>`_
```

but this raises a `WARNING: Mismatch: both interpreted text role prefix and reference suffix.`. Then I also tried

```
:class:`Class <https://api.documentation/some/path/to_class_constructor.htm>`
```

which doesn't raise a warning, but doesn't generate a hyperlink either.

As per Steve Piercy's comment below, the `sphinx.ext.extlinks` extension keeps the documentation a little cleaner, but it looses its semantic meaning, which I would prefer to keep.

Is it possible to somehow show the text references a class, and at the same time links to the external API documentation?

Comment: Is the external API documentation generated by Sphinx? If so, then you can use [intersphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html). Otherwise you can set a base URL with [extlinks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html).

Comment: Follow up: see my [comment on a recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569177/sphinx-multiple-nested-roles). Ideally the remote documentation was generated by Sphinx and would support intersphinx and its styles.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but cumbersome, due to the missing support for nested inline markup in rST.

The common workaround is to define a substitution and use this together with hyperlink syntax, e.g.

```
.. |class-1| replace:: :sub:`Class`

This is |class-1|__

__ https://api.documentation/some/path/to_class_constructor.htm
```