# Multiple (Nested) Roles in a Glossary

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

in my Sphinx docs I would like to create a glossary, potentially containing `:math:`, or other roles:

```
.. glossary::

    :math:`f(x)`
      Description
```

Is there any way to reference this entry with a text that has the same style as the glossary entry?

```
:term:`f(x)` Works, but is rendered as a plain hyperlink.

I want a hyperlink with the original styling instead:

:term:`:math:`f(x)``        Does not work. 
:term:`:math:`f(x)` <f(x)>` Also doesnt.
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: reST does not supported nested syntax, but there is a workaround as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57420716/2214933). You will need to grab the source HTML code that is generated for the glossary term and apply it accordingly.